# NodeJS Lambda function: how do I parse and detect a key inside an event

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using [Lambda-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local) to test my event, which will simulate a JSON file being sent to my S3 bucket and ultimately that i need to save.

Here is my event.json:

```
{
    "Records":[
      {
        "s3":{
          "bucket":{
          "name": "my.bucket"
      },
      "object":{
        "key": "report.json",
        "body": "{myKey: value}"
        }
     }
    }
   ]
  }
```

I would like to be able to run an `s3.putObject` if and only if the event contains a specific key in the body (in my little example, `mykey`).

I have attempted at the following:

```
exports.handler = (event) => {

    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    let eventKey = event.body.some((val) => {
        return Object.keys(val).includes("myKey");
    });
}
```

This fails like other attempts and it is because `body` is actually undefined. Is it possible to read a key from an incoming JSON event? Ultimately where the JSON is saved (inside the bucket) is dictated by the key inside the JSON file. This is fine if I work on a concrete file i either upload or send via SDK, but not if I use the event parameter. Can you please tell me whether this is the correct way to test my function to be production ready (meaning to be ready to be triggered by incoming events). Can you please help?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Amongst various attempts at also try this, but with no joy:

```
exports.handler = (event) => {

    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    const key = 'mykey';
    const obj = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2).body; 

    if(key in obj){
        console.log('yep')
    }
    else{
        console.log('no party');
    }
}
```

This time I am returned with the error:

```
{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'myKey' in undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'myKey' in undefined","    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:8:12)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:63:25)","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"]}
```

Any idea?

Comment: your JSON input is just a string; you should be able to analyse it (check its keys etc) if you convert it into an actual object using `JSON.parse(your_json_string)` or similar
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: tried that and it returns a very generic error 'Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0'. This is what i have done: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event));

Comment: my concern is that the JSON body is not currently available to be parsed in the incoming event. I do not know too much about Lambda and just started but I am struggling to understand why it is not possible to parse a JSON file.

Comment: It looks like it should be `event.Records[0].object.body` not `event.body`. And really you should be iterating through the `event.Records` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get an event parameter directly from the `event` object.
You could then perform a simple check for a specific key, dynamically or otherwise.

For example:

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {

  const key = 'mykey';
  const obj = event.someObj;

  if (key in obj) {
    // Key exists within the object.
    // Do something here ...
  }

}
```

**EDIT**

Because your body is actually a string, you may need to parse it first.
The error you get seems to indicate that your obj variable is undefined. What does your console.log above output?

```
exports.handler = (event) => {

    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    const key = 'mykey';
    const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)).body; 

    if(key in obj){
        console.log('yep')
    }
    else{
        console.log('no party');
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Okay I see now. Your `object.body` isn't a parseable object, so when trying to obtain the key naturally it will fail. You could look at ensuring the object.body is formatted correctly so that you can do JSON.parse over it. However, if you're not in control of the body, you can always check for the presence of the key in the following way:

```
exports.handler = (event) => {

    console.log('Received event body:', event.Records[0].s3.object.body);

    const key = 'mykey'; // The key you're looking for
    const keyExp = new RegExp('{^'+key); // RegExp for the key you're looking for.
    const bodyString = event.Records[0].s3.object.body; // Object.body as a string

    // Test the keyExp
    if(keyExp.test(bodyString)){
        console.log('yep')
    }
    else{
        console.log('no party');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Please see my edit. the in operator does not seem to work. Although at least I am now able to get hold of the body of the message.

Comment: @paranza Hey, I noticed that your console.log doesn't specify the .`body` property. Does the console.log output anything? It may be a string if so, in which case you might need to JSON.parse it (see my edit for an example) in order to get the body object.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error message as the one posted in my edit. Not sure why the in operator triggers an error. Any idea? Any other approach for just checking that the key exists? thank you

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the use of hasOwnProperty returns a similar error...a bit at loss here

Comment: @paranza - Take a look at my second edit. I tested it out with the example JSON event you supplied and it works as intended. It seems that your inner object.body isn't a real object (or at least not a valid one that can be parsed.) - I included an example that tests against the body string, however if you are able to change the events (and their format) then I can also create a version to work with that!

Comment: If you did want to parse the object.body correctly, each of the keys and values would need to be wrapped in escaped double quotes. For example:

`"{ \"mykey\" : \"someValue\" }"` would be JSON.parseable.

If you don't care about the positioning of the mykey, you can also determine whether that string exists anywhere within object.body using `bodyString.indexOf('mykey') !== -1` which would determine whether the substring of 'mykey' exists anywhere within object.body